# FFMPEG script to add 1 sec fade in the start and end of every clip

Tags: ffmpeg

I am making a music mix with more than 10 audio files. For this, I am trying to add an audio fade of 1 sec in the start and end of every single audio clip used for my mix when joining those audio clips. Can someone please help me with the ffmpeg program for this?

Answer (score 1):

script:

```
#!/bin/bash
LST=($(ls -1tr input*.mp3))
TOT=${#LST[*]}
f="${LST[0]}"
DUR=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$f")
echo $f $DUR
DUR=$(echo "$DUR - 1" | bc -l)
FCT=0
INP=("-i" "$f")
FLA="[0:a]afade=t=in:st=0:d=1,afade=t=out:st=${DUR}:d=1[0a]"
CO1="[0a]"

for (( i=1; i<=$(( $TOT -1 )); i++ )); do
  f="${LST[$i]}"
  DUR=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$f")
  echo $f $DUR
  DUR=$(echo "$DUR - 1" | bc -l)
  ((FCT+=1))
  INP+=("-i" "$f")
  FLA+=";
[${i}:a]afade=t=in:st=0:d=1,afade=t=out:st=${DUR}:d=1[${i}a]"
  CO1+="[${i}a]"
done

((FCT+=1))
ffmpeg "${INP[@]}" -filter_complex "
${FLA};
${CO1}concat=n=${FCT}:v=0:a=1[a]
" -map [a] -c:a aac -q:a 4 /tmp/output.mkv -hide_banner -y
```